# max of finite number of integrable functions is integrable

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

**Proposition**: Let $f_1, ..., f_n$ real valued integrable lebesgue functions in $(X, \mathfrak{M}, \mu)$ meausure space. Then $max\{f_1, ..., f_n\}$ is measurable.

**proof**: We have that $max\{f_1, ..., f_n\} = max\{f_1, max\{f_2, max\{...max\{f_{n-1}, f_n\}...\}\}\}$; as max of integrable lebesgue functions is integrable lebesgue function then $max\{f_1, ..., f_n\}$ is integrable lebesgue function.

There is some mistake?

Comment: No mistake, but then this seems so trivial unless you explain why the maximum of two functions $\max \{ f,g\}$ is integrable whenever $f,g$ are.  I know the answer, but want to make sure that you know it too.

Comment: $max\{f, g\} = \dfrac{f + g + |f - g|}{2}$

Comment: Perfect. That's why. All right, your question is done!